# Hosting Angular 4 app with node.js not working

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am trying to host an Angular 4 application with Node.js
I am following this guide: https://javascriptrocks.wordpress.com/2016/06/04/express-with-angular-cli-in-5-minutes/
However when I start the node.js server it just keeps on loading and doesnt show any page.
Folder layout:
    -dist
     --assets
     --app.js
     --index.html
     --inline.xxx.bundle.js
     --main.xxx.bundle.js
     --polyfills.xxx.bundle.js
     --styles.xxx.bundle.css
     --vendor.xxx.bundle.js

The app.js contents:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server running at port ' + port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

I start it with:
`node dist/app.js`

**EDIT:**
I got it working now. Not sure if its the right way:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.

sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('App started');
});
```

Comment: Paste your index.html

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @ContinuousError It's on the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually got it working this way:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.

sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('App started');
});
```